# Transforming an ansible list of lists to a list of dicts

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

I finally learned how to do nested lists with `product`, but I don't like that I have to access the results by indices. `product` produces a list of lists, and I want a list of dicts.

For example, the following code....

```yaml
- name: experimenting
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: Define some facts
    set_fact:
      people:
      - name: "Fred"
      - name: "John"
      animals:
      - name: "cat"

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ animals | product(people)  }}"
```

...produces the following output:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        [
            {
                "name": "cat"
            },
            {
                "name": "Fred"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "name": "cat"
            },
            {
                "name": "John"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

How can I transform that so it looks like:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            animal: {
                name: "cat"
            },
            person: {
                name: "Fred"
            }
        },
        {
            animal: {
                name: "cat"
            },
            person: {
                name: "John"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

In C#, I would use the LINQ `Select` statement, but I can't find the equivalent of that in ansible world.

Answer (score 1):

That one is not written using chatGPT as it is (at least temporarily) [forbidden by site rules](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1). Moreover, it includes some fixes on your initial question to respect best practice like using `set_facts` only when it is needed and looping in a task only when necessary.

This self explanatory playbook with intermediate debug should be quite easy to get and gives what you expect:

```yaml
---
- name: experiment
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    
    people:
      - name: "Fred"
      - name: "John"
    
    animals:
      - name: "cat"

    people_as_dict: "{{ ['people: '] | product(people) | map('join') | map('from_yaml') }}"

    animals_as_dict: "{{ ['animal: '] | product(animals) | map('join') | map('from_yaml') }}"

    people_animals: "{{ people_as_dict | product(animals_as_dict) | map('combine') }}"

  tasks:
    - name: Tranform people list so that each element is a dict
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: people_as_dict

    - name: Do the same thing as above with animals
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: animals_as_dict

    - name: combine every element to get expected resutl
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: people_animals
```

Demo run:

```
PLAY [experiment] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Tranform people list so that each element is a dict] *************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "people_as_dict": [
        {
            "people": {
                "name": "Fred"
            }
        },
        {
            "people": {
                "name": "John"
            }
        }
    ]
}

TASK [Do the same thing as above with animals] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "animals_as_dict": [
        {
            "animal": {
                "name": "cat"
            }
        }
    ]
}

TASK [combine every element to get expected resutl] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "people_animals": [
        {
            "animal": {
                "name": "cat"
            },
            "people": {
                "name": "Fred"
            }
        },
        {
            "animal": {
                "name": "cat"
            },
            "people": {
                "name": "John"
            }
        }
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Good example of [Using filters to manipulate data](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html), [Combining lists](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-lists) and [Jinja2 `map` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/complex_data_manipulation.html). It should become the accepted answer.

Comment: Sorry, but I hate this answer. Converting yaml to strings feels very hacky. My original answer feels much more pragmatic, regardless of what is considered bad practice.

Comment: Yaml is a string representation of a structured data. I don't see how building a yaml string representation and parsing it is hacky. This is actually quite common practice as it is basically happening anytime you interpret a jinja2 variable between double curly braces in Ansible. Meanwhile you are absolutely free to like whatever you wish even if feelings don't have much to do with efficiency. The answer you got from the here forbidden AI (which never gave me any fully satisfying answer so far) is definitely not optimized, in this specific case at least.